# Has anybody been able to install experimental features (relational databases) from ExtLib on top of Upgrade Pack 1?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

We have UP1 and we have a requirement for relational database connection with Microsoft SQL; I see several posts on Internet that mention this can be accomplished by installing experimental features from corresponding version of Extension Library on OpenNTF.org

Can someone outline what are the required steps for this.

Thanks in advance,
Pablo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same steps like installing the extLib from OpenNTF. unpack the zip and point the applikation installer to the updatesite. The installer will only install additional features on top of UP1. ( i.e experimental stuff )

Comment: Thanks @UlrichKrause for your response. Can you please elaborate more "The installer will only install additional features on top of UP1". I see the corresponding version for UP1 on OpenNTF is **853-20111215-0914c** inside updateSiteOpenNTF.zip I see **com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational_8.5.3.20111215-0914.jar** and **com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational.derby_8.5.3.20111215-0914.jar**. Should I select **Extended Components Library for XPages Feature 8.5.3.20111215-0914** feature only when I run installer?

Comment: You have to download the extension Library from openNTF and unpack the extlib_designer package. Then point to the updateside dir inside the unpacked stuff.
Only two features should be visible to be selected. Select both and then you have the wanted features.

And yes, this are the extended COmponents.